# WAMP server and PHP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I am using a [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server on a Windows Vista machine, and I am trying to do my first steps in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) programming.

The problem is that the PHP include function dosn't work, and I don't know what the problem is!   My code runs on other servers at work, but do not run in WAMP!

Comment: are you in htdocs? Can you try to provide more specifics?

Answer (score 0):

With WAMP server started try going to PHP > PHP Extensions from the taskbar icon and see if the extension that the function uses in enabled. Most of what you want should be available from this list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open php MyAdmin from Wamp - to make sure Apache is process is running - if not, nothing appears. If this is the issue, I would check if it could be problem related to port 80 (which happened to me). But if it DOES work, make sure that you use correct syntax for opening the php page as `http://localhost/my_page.php`